# How to select top 10 rows from information.schema.columns list

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
     FROM 
         INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
     WHERE 
         COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%MAIL%')
```

I am trying to get the top 10 rows from each of the tables within my search. Any ideas? SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

While nscheaffer's answer is valid, I feel obligated to tell you that you can get the exact same functionality without using a cursor, and also while using a query which might be a bit easier to implement.

Just concatenate all of the possible queries together based off the system tables and then execute them simultaneously, like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
;
SELECT @SQL = 
    (
    SELECT 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ' + OBJECT_NAME(C.Object_ID) + ';' + CHAR(10)
    FROM sys.Columns C
    INNER JOIN sys.Tables T
        ON C.Object_ID = T.Object_ID
        AND T.is_ms_shipped = 0
    WHERE C.Name LIKE '%Mail%'
    GROUP BY C.Object_ID
    ORDER BY C.Object_ID
    FOR XML PATH('')
    )
;
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL
;
```

If you want to check the SQL before it runs, just comment out the `EXEC` command and replace it with a `SELECT`, like this:

```
SELECT @SQL;
--EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a cursor to create dynamic SQL and then execute that SQL. Does this work for you?

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR (4000) = ''
DECLARE @Table_Name NVARCHAR(50)

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR 

SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%MAIL%'

OPEN TableCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @Table_Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @SQL = @SQL + '
    SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ' + @Table_Name + '
    GO
    '
    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @Table_Name
END

CLOSE TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor

EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @SQL
```